# Bad connection with MySQL connection string with TLS

Tags: mysql, azure, go, ssl

I am unable to connect to my MySQL database on Azure using Go. I am seeing:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:XXXXX
[mysql] 2019/08/09 16:42:17 packets.go:36: read tcp XXX.XXX.X.XX:XXXXX->XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
[mysql] 2019/08/09 16:42:23 packets.go:36: read tcp XXX.XXX.X.XX:XXXXX->XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
[mysql] 2019/08/09 16:42:29 packets.go:36: read tcp XXX.XXX.X.XX:XXXXX->XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
panic: driver: bad connection

goroutine 1 [running]:
db.ConnectToDB(0x134c7aa, 0x5, 0xc0000e6000, 0x9b)
    /Users/myuser/go/src/db/db-connection.go:113 +0x249
main.main()
    /Users/myuser/go/src/mydbapp/main.go:12 +0x58
```

I tried instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-go

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)


func ConnectToMydb() {

    mysqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("myusername@myservernameshort:mypassword@tcp" +
    "(myservenameshort.database.windows.net:1433)/mydbname?" +
    "&allowNativePasswords=true&tls=true&timeout=30s"
)

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected mydb!")
}
```

My JDBC equivalent connection string is as follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myservernameshort.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydbname;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30
```

and that works.

The instructions at the following link were not clear if I need to go that route:
https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterTLSConfig

Please guide how I can proceed/ if you need more information/ what I could try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db was mssql and not mysql. My bad. The port # should have given it away